# C# & SQL Server : escaping SQL column name AND param?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqldataadapter

I get that using reserved keywords as column names is frowned upon, but in a database that I didn't design I'm running into just that.

I understand escaping the column name as `tableName.[Count]` for any column using a reserved keyword, but what about in an instance where you're working within a custom data adapter?

My question is this, here's a mock update statement:

```
SqlComm = new SqlCommand("Update myTable Set <stuff>", sqlConn)
```

One of the updateable items is `Update myTable Set [Count] = @Count...`

Is there any escaping that needs to take place on `@Count` as well? Or would the above be the appropriate syntax?

Comment: No, you don't need to escape the parameter names, in fact the names of the parameters do not even need to match the column names (although for readability they should)